# Searchkick 2 nesting 'has_many'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have 3 classes.

```
Product, Command, CommandOption
```

I have search which work very nice. Search by product.
But I want search by `CommandOption` and returned my Product object, how is do this?

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base


extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug, use: :slugged



searchkick

  has_many :commands

  def search_data
    {
      name: name,

      #commands (has_many)
      command_captions: commands.map(&:caption).join(' '),
      command_numbers: commands.map(&:number).join(' '),

      #if I write here, then get error
      #command_option_caption: command_options.map(&:caption).join('')
    }
  end

end

class Command < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product

  has_many :command_options
end

class CommandOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :command
end
```

Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

simply in model `Product` added relation

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick

  has_many :commands
  has_many :command_options, through: :commands


  def search_data
    {
      name: name,

      #commands (has_many)
      command_captions: commands.map(&:caption).join(' '),
      command_numbers: commands.map(&:number).join(' '),
      #for commandoption model
      command_option_captions: command_options.map(&:caption).join(' ')
    }
  end

end
```